# .htaccess Rewrite an url with arguments in gif url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

after some research i am still not able to find a solution which work fine for me.

now i have an url like this :

--> http://www.localhost.com/images/values-lock/countdown-timer.php?time=201504051144

and i want to rewrite and make appear this url in the browser with the possibility to get the time param above :

-->   http://www.localhost.com/201504051144/timer.gif

actually my last try look like this :

--- .htaccess ---

```
  RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /images/values-locked/
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z])?([a-zA-Z])=([0-9]+)$ $1/timer.gif [QSA]
```

---

i am not use to rewrite url way yet but still looking the doc and topic around.

thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /images/values-lock/countdown-timer\.php\?time=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/timer.gif? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/timer\.gif$ images/values-lock/countdown-timer.php?time=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: thanx you a lot everyone for helping me, i fix my issue :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/timer\.gif$ /images/values-lock/countdown-timer.php?time=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /images/values-lock/
 RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/timer\.gif/?$ /images/values-lock/countdown-timer.php?time=$1 [QSA,L]
```